# Highstock - force x-axis displayed range regardless of data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a candlestick chart with grouped data and would like to be able to show a specific range based on a defined pixel width of each candle regardless of missing data.

```
plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
        pointWidth: 10,
        pointPadding:5
    }
 },
```

So if the total plotWidth is 700px and each candle is approx 15px and the dataGrouping is 1 minute there would be approx 47 mins in the xAxis.

I would imagine i could caculate and add the missing data/points but is there some way to force the xAxis to display a range and plot whatever data i have automatically?

Comment: Does `min` or `max` not work?

Comment: i've just tried calculating and setting the min max using chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minxAxisTime, currentTime) and the xaxis range shown is correct but the series no longer show even though there is corresponding data??

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle showing this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you can use or `pointPadding` or `pointWidth`, where width has higher priority.

Anyway, you can user ordinal axis (which is default behavior) to remove missing data between points. It means that points will be evenly spaced on a chart. You have only 10 points? Each will take the same amount of space, x-value will have lower priority.

This is example: http://jsfiddle.net/WbynW/

You can observe only 5 points, but each is 10px width, and each has the same distance between next one. Note xAxis labels (1. Jan, 11. Jan etc.)